# Space between .push array values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I've created **days names 7 checkboxes** and 1 `input type hidden`. If user click on days names which are checkboxes. Then their values print in the input.
**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="ml-4">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="monday" name="days_names" value="Monday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="monday">Monday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tuesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Tuesday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="wednesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Wednesday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="thursday" name="day_name_selector" value="Thursday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="thursday">Thursday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="friday" name="day_name_selector" value="Friday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="friday">Friday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="saturday" name="day_name_selector" value="Saturday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="saturday">Saturday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sunday" name="day_name_selector" value="Sunday">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="sunday">Sunday</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="" class="form-control selected_days_names" name="days_names" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='day_name_selector']").change(function() {
            var final = new Array();
            $('input[name="day_name_selector"]:checked').each(function(){        
                var values = $(this).val();
                final.push(values);
            });
            $('.selected_days_names').val(final);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, I am getting values in input without spaces like this --> `Sunday,Monday,Tuesday`..... I want it to show the values in input like this --> `Sunday, Monday, Tuesday` with spaces between values.
**How can I get spaces between values? Please help me**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because jQuery is calling `join()` on the array when displaying it in the value of the field. By default this uses `','` to separate the values.

Instead you want to use `join(', ')` (note the trailing space) so you can call that manually when setting the `val()`:

```
$('.selected_days_names').val(final.join(', '));
```

Here's a full working example, which is using `map()` instead of `each()` to be slightly more succinct:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("input[name='day_name_selector']").change(function() {
    var final = $('input[name="day_name_selector"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    $('.selected_days_names').val(final.join(', '));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ml-4">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="monday" name="days_names" value="Monday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monday">Monday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tuesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Tuesday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="wednesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Wednesday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="thursday" name="day_name_selector" value="Thursday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="thursday">Thursday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="friday" name="day_name_selector" value="Friday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="friday">Friday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="saturday" name="day_name_selector" value="Saturday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="saturday">Saturday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sunday" name="day_name_selector" value="Sunday">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="sunday">Sunday</label>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="" class="form-control selected_days_names" name="days_names" />
```

Also note that the `Monday` checkbox doesn't have the `name` attribute in the selector, so doesn't appear to work. I'm not sure if that's intentional or a typo.

Answer (score 4):

`final` is an array, and when you call `.val`, the expression passed gets automatically converted into a string. When an array is converted to a string, it will, by default, join by just a comma, like `.join(',')`. If you want to join by anything else (like a comma and a space), you have to do so explicitly:

```
$('.selected_days_names').val(final.join(', '));
```

Also consider declaring the array with `[]` instead of `new Array()`:

```
var final = [];
```

You can also consider constructing the array all at once with `.map`:

```
  var final = $('input[name="day_name_selector"]:checked')
    .map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    })
    .get();
```